# how to split columns by deliminator so I can include them in value counts

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZUpC.png)

I am trying to separate the columns with multiple artists by the comma so I can add them all up with `.valuecounts`. Otherwise it will include "Metro Boomin, The Weeknd, 21 Savage" as a separate artist rather than count it as "Metro Boomin", "The Weeknd" and "21 Savage"

I have tried this code:

```
test2 = alldata.apply(lambda x: artistsbypopularitylist.split(","), axis=1)
```

but the error is saying there is no attribute split for the 'function' object

I also tried:

```
alldata[['Artist1','Artist2']] = alldata['Artist Name(s)'].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

but is saying the columns must be the same length as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excel formula that will do what you need. It's not python, but it does the trick for all your data with this one single formula. Just update your column B range with the one in this formula and press enter:

```
=TRIM(
    LET(
        list, A1:A3,
        MAKEARRAY(
            ROWS(list),
            MAX(LEN(list) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(list, " ", "")) + 1),
            LAMBDA(r, c, INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(list, r), ","), c))
        )
    )
)
```